# Не получается сгруппировать результат регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не понимаю почему он не хочет сохранять результат в группы?

Вот регулярное выражение

```
(?:(\d+)-?)+ /// То есть он ловит примерное следущее 53453-3234-324234-24324-5234
```

Мне нужно чтобы результат сохрянялся в группы:

```
1. 53453
2. 3234
3. 324234
4. 24324
5. 5234
```

Но почему-то сейчас он сейвит в группы не так как надо, на данный момент он сохраняет только одну группу и это последняя то есть `5234`.
Еще хотелось бы не сохрянять тире в группы что собственно выше я показал.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48456/discussion-on-question-by-maximpro-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие пробелемы в PHP приходится решать за 2 шага:

- Разбить текст на (вычленить) нужные группы (тут можно использовать [`(\d+):{(\d+(?:-\d+)*)}`](https://regex101.com/r/fq6HR3/1)).
- Обработать тексты, захваченные группой 2 (можно с помощью `explode("-", $m[2])`, в более трудных случаях можно воспользоваться вторым `preg_match(_all)`).

Всё можно сделать в `preg_replace_callback`, чтобы получить желаемый результат за 1 проход.

[Примерный код на PHP](https://ideone.com/4QQHQK):

```
$s = "4:{227-130-191},8:{97},9:{98},14:{99},15:{195-160}";
$ar = array();
preg_replace_callback('/(\d+):{(\d+(?:-\d+)*)}/', function($m) use (&$ar) {
    $ar[$m[1]] = explode("-", $m[2]);
}, $s);
print_r($ar);
```

Comment: хорошо, хоть это не совсем то чего я ожидал, но сильно приближено к тому что нужно

Comment: В .NET можно было бы всё сделать по-вашему, там есть `CaptureCollection`, в Python PyPi *regex* есть `captures`, но в РНР нет такого.

Comment: понятно, ну такой вариант тоже сойдет, он не громоздкий все же

Answer (score 0):

если нужно пропускать все, кроме чисел, то подойдет:

```
    (?:(\d+))+
```

код на php

```
    <?php
    $re = '/(?:(\d+))+/';
    $str = '53453-3234-324234-24324-5234';

    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

    // Print the entire match result
    print_r($matches);
```

Comment: нет это не то что нужно

Comment: тогда, все же в 2 этапа и с использованием непонравившегося вам explode ^_^ через регулярку `$re = '/(([\d\-]+))/';` получаете все группы с `-`, а дальше через explode разбиваете, на нужные массивы.

Comment: это было выяснено раньше, explode мне не не нравится просто использование только его не дает той гибкости которые дают регулярки

Answer (score -1):

Код будет примерно таким:

```
$numbersString = '53453-3234-324234-24324-5234';
$arrayOfNumbers = explode('-', $numbersString);

print_r($arrayOfNumbers);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 53453
    [1] => 3234
    [2] => 324234
    [3] => 24324
    [4] => 5234
)
```

Comment: Ну вы издеваетесь? Я просил использовать explode?